# How to export ProcessHelper in a TypeScript file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've defined a class that uses ProcessHelper.hostName and I want to know how to import ProcessHelper in the class

Comment: posting your code, tsconfig.json etc. would be useful if u want to get better help

Comment: What development environment are you using? Some (like Visual Studio ctrl-dot) will do this for you automatically via a key combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting/Importing is described in detail here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

In your case, you could export your class as:

```
export class ProcessHelper { ... }
```

and import it somewhere else as:

```
import { ProcessHelper }  from './path/to/process-helper';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an export-import syntax for legacy modules and a standard export format for modern ES6 modules

```
// export the default export of a legacy (`export =`) module
export import MessageBase = require('./message-base');

// export the default export of a modern (`export default`) module
export { default as MessageBase } from './message-base';

// export an interface from a legacy module
import Types = require('./message-types');
export type IMessage = Types.IMessage;

// export an interface from a modern module
export { IMessage } from './message-types';
```

more details

```
import 'jquery';                        // import a module without any import bindings
import $ from 'jquery';                 // import the default export of a module
import { $ } from 'jquery';             // import a named export of a module
import { $ as jQuery } from 'jquery';   // import a named export to a different name
import * as crypto from 'crypto';       // import an entire module instance object

export var x = 42;                      // export a named variable
export function foo() {};               // export a named function

export default 42;                      // export the default export
export default function foo() {};       // export the default export as a function

export { encrypt };                     // export an existing variable
export { decrypt as dec };              // export a variable as a new name
export { encrypt as en } from 'crypto'; // export an export from another module
export * from 'crypto';                 // export all exports from another module
                                        // (except the default export)
```